# Viewing of Crystal Report Form Crashes in Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crash, windows-installer

I have an application that uses Crystal Reports. Now in my Development environment, I have Crystal Report installed, so the both the development version and the release works fine.

However, when the Release version of the Setup is installed in a different PC which doesn't have Crystal Report Installed, the App crash when trying to load the Report.

It is obvious that, the DLLs required for Crystal Report are missing. I have added 6 DLLs into the setup project but it still crashes.

The DLLs added are listed below.

1. CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
2. CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework
3. CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore
4. CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
5. CrystalDecisions.Shared
6. CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Do I need to add anything else. In the Reference section of the project, no other name is listed that Beings With CrystalDecisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by installing Crystal Reports explicitly on the user PC.
By reading posts elsewhere, this appeared to be the only way.